# Logs via qDebug() are invisible when run via docker-compose

Tags: qt, docker-compose, qdebug

I have written a Qt application which logs to console via `qDebug()`. When run inside a docker container, the application logs are visible as normal. But when the same docker image is run via `docker-compose up`, there is no output visible at all. How does this come?

**Edit:**

The output is not visible either, if I try to view it via docker logs in the following way:

```
docker run -d --rm -name test test-image
docker logs test
```

Working:

```
docker run -it --rm test-image
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution. My `docker run` was missing the `-t` flag:

```
docker run -it --rm -t test-image
```

The equivalent option for the docker-compose config is:

```
tty: true
```

Hope this is helpfull to someone.